# how to convert my colums data to rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on an online exam database in sql server where i have one table  with following  structure :-

```
id question option1 option2 option3 option4 option1_image option2_image option3_image option4_image
```

and i want data in following format

```
id  options  option_image
```

in option column, i want to get all options value and in option_image column i want all images. i am using following query

```
select  id,Options,Option_Image
from Questions
unpivot
(
  Options
  for col in (option1, option2,option3,option4)

) u
unpivot
(
Option_Image
for img in(option1_image,option2_image,option3_image,option4_image)
) v
```

But it dosnt work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is good for large amount of record 
but you can try this

```
select ID,option1,option1_img from Questions
union all
select ID,option2,option2_img from Questions
union all
select ID,option3,option3_img from Questions
union all
select ID,option4,option4_img from Questions
```